# How can I solve $x^{40}+3x^5 \equiv 0 \mod \ 13$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How can I solve:  $x^{40} + 3x^5 \equiv 0 \ mod \ 13$

I have no idea about how to proceed.

EDIT:

$x^{40}=x^{12\cdot3}\cdot x^4 \equiv x^4$ mod 13. So $x^4 + 3x^5 \equiv 0$ mod 13, and $x^4(1+3x) \equiv 0$ mod 13. $x^4(1+3x)$ must be divisible by 13 so $1+3x=13 \rightarrow x=4$

Thanks!.

Comment: Hint: for all integers $x$, we have $x^{13}\equiv x$ mod $13$. So what is $x^{40}$ mod $13$? Now you can easily factorise and solve.

Comment: Hint: There are just 13 different cases :-)

Comment: @ToyK I edited the post before your answer. Could you check if I am wrong?. Thx.

Comment: @Phi Yes, that's right. Also the trivial solution of x=0.

Comment: Your solution seems to assume that $x^{12}\equiv 1$ mod $13$. But this is only true if $x$ is _non-zero_ mod $13$. That is why I wrote $x^{13}\equiv x$, which is true for _all_ $x$. (And indeed, as @1110101001 points out, you missed the zero solution.)

Comment: Ok. Thanks both of you.